# Carregar arquivo no diretório atual ao rodar o irb

Tags: ruby, irb

É possível chamar o irb passando como parâmetro uma biblioteca a ser carregada (required):

```
irb -r date
```

Mas isso não funciona se eu quiser carregar um arquivo no diretório onde o comando é executado:

```
irb -r meuscript
```

(supondo que existe o arquivo `meuscript.rb`)

Acho que isso funcionava em versões mais antigas. Como funciona agora?

Comment: Qual versão do Ruby você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando Ruby 1.9.3 ou 2.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Para as versões do Ruby a partir do 1.9.x, é necessário passar o caminho completo do arquivo, seja relativo, ou absoluto, pois o diretório corrente foi removido do `LOAD_PATH`, então é necessário fazer:

```
irb -r ./meuscript
```

indicando que o arquivo `meuscript.rb` está no diretório corrente.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode passar o nome do arquivo. Por exemplo:

```
irb meuscript.rb
```

Como apontado pelo rodrigorgs o irb irá sair após executar o arquivo.

A solução que vejo para isso no momento é usar `load` dentro do irb:

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p194 :001 > load 'meuscript.rb'
```

Comment: Não funciona da mesma forma que no exemplo do `irb -r date`. No seu exemplo o irb fecha depois que o arquivo é carregado em vez continuar no modo interativo.

Answer (score 2):

O caminho em que o `irb` vai procurar suas bibliotecas é decidido por algumas variáveis de ambiente (e.g. `GEM_PATH`, `GEM_HOME`), o que (geralmente) não inclui o diretório atual. Uma forma de modificar o caminho usado nessa busca é a flag `-I`.

Por exemplo, suponha que você está em um diretório com um arquivo `my_app.rb`. Uma forma de iniciar o `irb` com esse arquivo carregado é:

```
$ irb -I. -r my_app
# Você também pode fazer:
$ irb -I.
>> require 'my_app'
```

Isso é bem útil quando se está testando scripts soltos, mexendo em projetos que não obedecem à organização de diretórios das gems, etc.

Comment: Isso é especialmente eficiente quando há mais de um arquivo. Por exemplo, os fontes de uma gem se encontram dentro do diretório `lib` por convenção. Ao executar `irb -I ./lib`, obtem-se acesso a gem como se ela estivesse instalada.

Answer (score 0):

Quando estou no IRB e preciso usar uma lib própria, entro nele e escrevo:

```
require File.expand_path '<nome_do_arquivo>'
```

Detalhe, não coloca .rb, só .